# Ender 3 V2 blank screen and LCD continuous beeping with clicks

Tags: marlin, creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, electronics

So I have been having an ongoing problem with my printer that I just can't solve. I don't usually ask the questions on stack exchanges until my problem gets unsolvable. Unfortunately like this one

**Printer**: Creality Ender 3 V2

**Current Board**: [Creality v4.2.7 (Silent Motor)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TFTVTXK)

**Background**: This started when I accidentally fried the T20 chip on the v4.2.2 mainboard when I tried to install the BLTouch incorrectly (I looked at the photo upside down) and and also accidentally pulled the wire out and what I guess is why the T20 chip was fried. I thought at first the PSU was the one causing the trouble at first so I replaced it. Then found the burnt chip and decided to upgrade the board to a v4.2.7. I installed everything correctly according to a video that I found somewhere on YouTube.

**Current Problem(s)**: When I turn on the machine the light on the mainboard is on but there is continuous beeping coming from the display with small clicks like a clock every 1 sec. or so. The backlight to the display is on but nothing is shown. I just found with a multimeter that the bed and nozzle terminals give no volts back.

**Firmware**: I have tried to update the firmware to the [official one off of Creality's website](https://forums.creality3dofficial.com/download/ender-series/ender-3-v2/) and also using the source code for [Marlin v2.0.7.2](https://marlinfw.org/meta/download) with PlatformIO. The tutorial I followed was here:

**Update [3/24]**: Found that the firmware seems to not flash even after giving the .bin file a different name.

**Extra Thoughts**: I currently have no idea what to do. I think I might replace the LCD and its cable. I have only printed a few things and just want to get back to it but I don't want to buy a whole new printer to do so. I feel like I get closer to getting back to it every time I fix something but I'm starting to lose hope that it's just a never ending problem loop. I appreciate any help given.

Comment: v 4.2.7 of what? is that a creatlity boars? What video did you watch? It reeks of mis-configured firmware.

Comment: Yeah, it's the creality board v4.2.7(silent motor) https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07TFTVTXK/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_fabc_5M1XXQQJEQAK609C0T8D?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1. And there are a lot of tutorials but I think the one that I watched was https://youtu.be/y87P7K5DTMU cause it was pretty simple. I did no major changes to the marlin firmware except change the bed sizing and environment.

Comment: Also it was doing the same problem even without the firmware change. I tried it straight out of the box and got this problem then tried flashing the firmware but still got the same problems.

Comment: When you say you tried to compile your own Marlin firmware, which files did you pull for your configuration settings? Did the firmware successfully compile?

Comment: @Rykara Pretty much, I followed the tutorial here https://youtu.be/y87P7K5DTMU I used Marlins most recent release v2.0.7.2 https://marlinfw.org/meta/download/ and the firmware did successfully compile

Comment: Which [printer configuration](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Configurations/tree/release-2.0.7.2/config/examples) file did you use?

Comment: @Rykara I used the /Creality/Ender-3 V2

Comment: Computers will act like that if memory or boards aren't plugged in well.  Worst case is a component faiure on the mainboard.

Comment: @PerryWebb Hopefully it's not a component failure. I don't mind breaking out my small soldering kit but I would like to avoid it if possible cause I suck at it.

Comment: Note: wrong firmware could have settings that cause a component to functionally fail with those settings, especially wrong timing.

Comment: Could be a bad or incorrectly formatted SD card. I think the card needs to be FAT32 format. Try reformating and/or using a different SD card?

Comment: @Rykara Thank you very much! I didn't know that it had to be formated to a specific type, I'm on a Mac and didn't have the FAT32 option, and I think I tried NTFS on Windows just to be safe but didn't try FAT32 for some dumb reason. Somehow it was just as simple as that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [the comment](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/15922/ender-3-v2-blank-screen-and-lcd-continuous-beeping-with-clicks/20921#comment30127_15922) from @Rykara, they led me to the answer:

> Could be a bad or incorrectly formatted SD card. I think the card needs to be FAT32 format. Try reformating and/or using a different SD card?

The whole problem was kinda a firmware issue but on the SD card side. The reason why it wasn't flashing was because I didn't flash the SD card to use the FAT32 format. Unfortunately I tried every other format option except that one before hand, mostly because I am mainly on a Mac. Now there is no more problems and I am back on track to printing. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the constant beeping, black screen issue.

I went to [Creality Cloud Firmware for 3D Printers: Ender 3 v2 Mainboard version 4.2.2](https://www.crealitycloud.com/software-firmware/firmware?type=2&keyword&system=0&subType=60067926229435d86f60789a&hardware=V4.2.2).

I installed `Ender-3 V2-Marlin-2.0.1 - V1.2.1 - Filament` because I have the Ender 3 v2 4.2.2 board. This is the only firmware that loaded. I then reran all the other compatible firmware and it loaded them fine. But it only fixed itself once I ran the one with `- Filament`. **No idea why!?!?!** I spent hours and this is what did it.

The site's root is [Creality Cloud: Download Creality Firmware and Software](https://www.crealitycloud.com/software-firmware).

Comment: Nice answer, and hopefully it will be useful to someone else. However, while the symptoms were similar, it seems that the underlying cause is probably different from that of the OP's, which, in their case, was the SD format needing to be FAT32.